# Microsoft Access 2016 - Insert SQL query not adding in correct row count

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a Query "NP_Compare_SPC" and a Table "NP_Compare_Table".  NP_Compare_Table is currently empty and I am trying to insert the full contents of the query into the table.

When using the following code, I get **16042** rows inserted:

```
INSERT INTO NP_Compare_Table (Time_of_NP, [NID], [TX NU], [RX NU], [TX SPC Time], [RX SPC Time], [TX SPC Data], [RX SPC Data])

SELECT Q.[Time_of_NP], Q.[NID], Q.[TX NU], Q.[RX NU], Q.[TX SPC Time], Q.[RX SPC Time], Q.[TX SPC Data], Q.[RX SPC Data]

FROM NP_Compare_SPC Q
```

If I remove the [RX NU] field from the insertion, I get **16123** rows inserted. Using the following:

```
INSERT INTO NP_Compare_Table (Time_of_NP, [NID], [TX NU], [TX SPC Time], [RX SPC Time], [TX SPC Data], [RX SPC Data])

SELECT Q.[Time_of_NP], Q.[NID], Q.[TX NU], Q.[TX SPC Time], Q.[RX SPC Time], Q.[TX SPC Data], Q.[RX SPC Data]

FROM NP_Compare_SPC Q
```

The first code fails to insert 81 rows. These 81 rows all contain null values for [RX NU] in the query the data is coming from, but so does [RX SPC Data].  Removing [RX SPC Data] from the insert statement has now effect on the number of rows inserted though.

I have tried using various primary keys, default values, wrapping [RX NU] in a Nz() call, but can never get Access to add in these rows unless I omit adding the [RX NU] in the INSERT call.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you have a trigger on the table.

Comment: Sounds like the [RX NU] field doesn't like Null and empty strings. What if you insert a fixed dummy value?

Comment: Did you check Required property of the field? Validation rule?

Comment: I have tried using a "dummy value" by wrapping [RX NU] in a NZ() call, which should replace every null instance with a 0 in the SELECT statement.